# position().top doesn't change after adding elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

so i have a div in a div like this

```
<div id="container"> 
<div id="bottom"> </div>
</div>
```

container is absolute positioned.

i am adding elements using .before()

```
$("#bottom").before('<p>Some Paragraph</p>');
```

then i am trying to scroll down to the bottom of the container

```
$("#container").scrollTop($('#bottom').position().top);
```

it works for a while but then stops working.

if i print "$('#bottom').position().top", i see that it increments up to some point and then stops.

the reason i am doing this way is because i also have an animation before scrolling and it works fine with the animation but as i said up to some point.

the only temporary solution i came up with was this(basically put some large number).

```
 $("#container").scrollTop(10000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `offset()` instead of `position()`:

```
$("#container").scrollTop($('#bottom').offset().top);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: besides, offset is relative to document. but i am trying to get relative to the parent, so position should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a plugin for the scrolling?

[Jquery ScrollTo does a good job!](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$(...).scrollTo( $('#container'), timeInMs );
```

Answer (score 0):

My case I noticed that right after I added the elements on the page, I needed a small delay for the browser to complete rendering the new height of the elements.

The solution was:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#container").scrollTop($('#bottom').position().top);
}, 50);
```

PS.: 50 is an particularly arbitrary number, it works with just 0 in my case.